# Using Google-signin API without billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I was working on a website and needed to add a continue-with-google button. I am a kinda noob though, I was asked to pay before integrating it into my website from my google dev console

so, my question is could id create the button without having to pay or start my free trial?
or if someone could just link a tutorial or tell me how to add a functioning signing/continue-with-google button

Comment: Each Google service and each Google Cloud service has its terms. Edit your question to specify which service and API you plan to use. In general, you will need to create a Google Cloud project and enable billing. Some services such as the Gemini API have free usage (60 requests per minute) via API Key. The Vertex AI Gemini API is a paid service and requires a billing account and the cloud credits apply. Some AI services have a free tier offering. Provided that you use services within the API quota or within the free tier you will not be billed.

Comment: there, I've edited it, I think you got lil bit confused when I talked about AI actually meant i asked ChatGPT to teach me the steps involved but it didn't work that's why I came here : ).